# How to get Current System Time in MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

in a procedure Need to get current system time and compare the time with already stored start time to update another column to a default value if matches. How to get the System time  and better if i can get the time in UTC.

Is it better to create a function to get the systime and pass that as a arg. Whats the best approach to write the stored procedure in sql.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `now()` or `current_timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use this in the SP to get your system time in UTC:

SELECT Convert(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), Time)

However, I cannot tell you if it's a benefit or detriment over using it in a function.

Comment: That's Microsoft SQL Server syntax. MySQL doesn't have a function `GetUTCDate()`

Comment: Yep, that's my mistake. Haven't used MySql in some time, but i believe it's UTC_DATE(). Correcting above.

Comment: Might want to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`, because `UTC_DATE()` always has a time of 00:00:00.